# Django: How to iterate over two one-two-many table relationships?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a simple web page that queries three tables. There is a `Company` table that has a one-to-many relationship with a `Position` table, as well as a one-to-many relationship with a `Project` table.

The goal is to have the page display a given company once, along with all positions and and projects associated with said company. Then, move on to display the next company, any positions held there and projects completed.

Below is the closest I've come to getting this right. But, the obvious problem is that if there is more than one project associated with a given company, you'll see that company listed more than once.

I'm new to Django, so in the interest of learning, I wanted to beat my own head sufficiently hard before asking for help; but I could really use some fresh ideas at this point.

Also: I can see how a nested for loop might work here, but I'm just not clear on how the mechanics of that would work with the query, and then within the template.

Models:

```
from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name   

class Position(models.Model):
    position_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    position_title = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('professional.Company',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
    begin_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position_title   

class Project(models.Model):
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('professional.Company',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

View:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView

from professional.models import Company



class ProfessionalHome(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'professional/professional_home.html'


class TechnologyListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'professional/__technology.html'
    context_object_name = 'technology_list'

    def get_queryset(self):        
        return Company.objects.values('company_name','position__position_title', 'project__project_name')
```

HTML and template:

```
{% for job in technology_list %}

    <h1>{{job.company_name}}</h1>
    <h1>Position: {{job.position__position_title}}</h1>
    <h1>project: {{job.project__project_name}}</h1>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of values in `get_queryset` method, you can return the actual queryset and then iterate over it to build your view.

```
def get_queryset(self):        
        return Company.objects.all()
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for job in technology_list %}

    <h1>{{job.company_name}}</h1>
    {% for position in job.position_set.all() %}
        <h1>Position: {{position.position_title}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for project in job.position_set.all() %}
        <h1>project: {{project.project_name}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I was able to get this working pretty quickly. I just had a couple of syntax issues. `position_set.all()` needed the parans removed to make it `position_set.all` ; and the second-inner loop needed to be `job.project_set.all` and it worked! Thanks for the help, @Pranav!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over companies, then you should use the Company model as the basis for your view, not Technology. Also, you should avoid `values` and `values_list` unless you know you have a good reason, which you don't here. You can use `prefetch_related()` to reduce the number of reverse queries. So:

```
class TechnologyListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):        
        return Company.objects.all.prefetch_related('project','position')
```

...

```
{% for company in company_list %}

    <h1>{{company.company_name}}</h1>
    {% for position in company.position_set.all %}
      <h1>Position: {{ position.position_title }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for project in company.project_set.all %}
      <h1>project: {{ project.project_name }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

(Note, you should avoid giving your ForeignKey fields names ending in "_id". The Django field refers to the entire Company, not the ID; the fields should be called just `company`. The underlying database will be suffixed with `_id` anyway. Also, you don't need to use model_name prefixes on all your fields; it will be obvious from the object they are accessed on.)

Comment: Excellent advice, which I will certainly follow going forward. Thank you for your insights.